# Как реализовать уведомления Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Возможно ли как-нибудь в ElectronJS дать разрешение на уведомления в Windows? Оповещения не нужно создавать вручную, а необходимо чтобы их подтягивало из сайта (типо нативное приложение и т.д и т.п)

Comment: а зачем разрешение? что блокирует?

Comment: По факту, приложение Electron это окно браузера. Как известно, если перенаправить по ссылке внутри приложения автоматически (ибо приложение на базе адаптивного сайта), то, по аналогии с браузером, необходимо дать разрешение на вывод оповещений с этого сайта на рабочий стол. По умолчанию ведь уведомления отключены